# Jquery datatable issue with column sorting

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am working Jquery data table where I need to sorting icon and sorting/search false for one column

Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#tblUsers').DataTable({
            "searching": true,
            "ordering": true,
            "pagingType": "full_numbers",
            "ajax": "GetUsers",
            "columnDefs": [{
                "targets": 0,
                "data": "Id",
                "orderable": false,
                "searchable": false,
                "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                    return '<a href="MangeUser/' + data + '">Edit User</a>';
                }
            }],
            "columns": [
                {
                    "data": "Id"
                },
                { "data": "FirstName" },
                { "data": "LastName" },
                { "data": "UserName" },
                { "data": "RoleName" }
            ]
        });
    });
```

and html is as below

```
<table id="tblUsers" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>FirstName</th>
                    <th>LastName</th>
                    <th>Email Id</th>
                    <th>RoleName</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
```

Now even after setting orderable/searchable to false its still showing when page is loaded first time but when I click somewhere else then icon is gone

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add order in your datatable options to empty array, like this

```
order: []
```

because by default it applies order for 0th column and so it shows the sorting icon even though we have made it non sortable. By setting this property you are overriding this behavior

```
 $('#tblUsers').DataTable({
            "order" : [], // this new option
            "searching": true,
            "ordering": true,
            "pagingType": "full_numbers",
             ...
```